# How to set a cookie value on page load with PHP before it is retrieved in a WordPress template part?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I would like to set a cookie once in functions.php or header.php with the value depending on if a string is found in the url. Here is my code for that, currently in my functions.php file:

```
add_action('init', 'set_region_cookie', 1);
function set_region_cookie() {

    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    $url_string = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $six_months_from_now = time()+60*60*24*180;
    // If user is loading the UK English version of the site, set the region cookie to gb, else set to us
    if ( strpos($url_string,'en_gb') !== false ) {
        setcookie('region', 'gb', $six_months_from_now, '/' );
    } else {
        setcookie('region', 'us', $six_months_from_now, '/' );
    }
}
```

However, I notice that if I load a page with the following code inside a template part, I do not get the posts I was expecting based on the cookie value until I refresh the page again:

```
    $product_posts_args = [
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'tax_query'   => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'market_sector',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ $market_sector ]
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'region',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ $_COOKIE['region'] ]
        ],
    ],
    'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
];

$products = get_posts( $product_posts_args );
```

`$_COOKIE['region']` is giving me the last cookie value, not what it should be updating to in my functions.php and what I see in Chrome's Dev Tools.

How can I set the cookie before it is retrieved in my template part in `$product_posts_args`?

Comment: This is because cookie handling from the server side is done once in the header and at the time you load the page the first time it is not set yet. Therefore, you could simply use a global var (e.g., `$GLOBALS['region']`). Set it in the hook and call it in the template part

Comment: @user1165759 Thanks, that is helpful and your solution worked!